# Can I create an internet whitelist using only the packages availible on a clean Ubuntu install? (maybe /etc/hosts.allow?)

Tags: proxy, hosts, blacklist

I want to **not** be able to go to any site unless it's on a whitelist, and I'd rather not use something like Privoxy, can I do that with Ubuntu?

I'm thinking that perhaps I can use `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hosts.allow`, and/or `/etc/hosts.deny`. My first thought would be to somehow block everything using `hosts.deny` and then create the whitelist in `hosts.allow`. Is that possible? And if so how do I define something like "all sites direct to localhost" in `hosts.deny` and then "except these sites" in `hosts.allow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block all sites with `hosts.deny` you should put `ALL: ALL` in your `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

But there are some better ways to do this, for example:

- Using a firewall like `iptables`, with firewall you can block all HTTP, HTTPS, whatever traffic you want and allow it for some spacial IP, domain, etc.

  Read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212233/iptables-to-block-all-websites
- Using something like `dnsmasq`:

  Read this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-block-all-websites-except-2-a-667350/